# Theorem with an example

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this theorem [image]
[image]

In the paper they give an example:
[image]

But here $H_1$ is not satisfied !

How to correct it please?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163788/theorem-with-an-example

Comment: You have posted this question simultaneously here and [on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/163788/theorem-with-an-example). It is not a good thing to do, definitely not without adding links to other copies of the question. You can find several discussions on [meta-tag:cross-posting] on meta, for example http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/i-found-mo-has-been-included-in-se-network-today

Answer (score 1):

Also $H_2$ is NOT satisfied, I think it is a typo and is should be:

$f(t,u)=81u^2+4015\sin u +tu$ (or atleast along those lines)  since $H_1$ is then satisfied and:

$\int_0^u81v^2+4015\sin v +tvdv=(81/2)u^2-4015\cos u +(1/2)u^2t\le (82/2)u^2+4015\lt (\pi^4/2)+4015$

So $H_2$ is satisfied but it wasn't before.